# Rerun a command through piping which match a specific pattern

Tags: terminal, command-history

Say I would like to recall and run a command (eg)

```
wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

that I already use a day ago. I used the instruction

```
history | grep skype
```

which example output is

```
 1584  sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux 
 1585  sudo snap install skype 
 1824  cd skype/
 1829  wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
 2001  history | grep skype
```

How to extend the piping to run directly the process `1829` (without writing a new command `!1829`)?

Comment: How would you proceed to select the right entry if there are more than one matches in the history, as in your example?

Comment: If I manage to tighten the output say with `| grep "go.skype.com"` or something similar. What would be the next steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "greping" the history you could just use the reverse-search.

If you press `[ctrl]` + `[r]` (both keys at the same time) you will search backwards in your command-history.

So if you want to re-execute (for instance)

```
wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

you could just press `[ctrl]` + `[r]`, type in `skype` and then it should already display the command.

If this wasn't the last command you can cycle through the history pressing `[ctrl]` + `[r]` again.

Comment: Hum! It is a way to fix my problem. Great!!!!